# How much memory does a class get if there is no static methods or blocks and no object

Tags: java

During a recent interview, interviewer asked me this question:

If there is no object is created for a class and there are no static methods or blocks in a class, just some instance variables; will that class get memory? if no, will that class get any space in RAM?

As per my understanding, if static directly instantiate the block or method, but if there are no static blocks or method, no memory will be allocated.

Also, since we have not created any object hence, no instantiation of class will take place

So I said no memory will be allocated.

was I right? please confirm

I

Answer (score 1):

> will that class get memory?

Everything which exists in the program uses memory.

> if no, will that class get any space in RAM?

RAM == Memory, so if no => no.

> no memory will be allocated.

No memory will be allocated for the fields.  Something needs to record that the class was loaded.  It will have a default constructor (or at least one constructor) and that has to go somewhere,.

> So I said no memory will be allocated, was I right?

If you justified your answer, you could argue either way.  Java Developers often only count heap memory, so "no" might be fine.

BTW Try running a program with one line which loads an empty class.  You will find that about 10,000 objects will have been created to get to that point.  You could argue any amount of memory really.

Answer (score 0):

In typical JVMs, classes get loaded on-demand.

In your description everything sounds as if the class was not accessed by any part of the program: no static access, no object creation. This means that indeed the class consumes no heap memory at all, at least if the class lives in its own `.class` file.

If it lives in a `.jar` file though, that file is typically mapped into RAM, but that is not really expensive.

Comment: Thanks, so if have written int i =20; in Ram will it get 4 bytes of memory?

Comment: It depends. Create a new question if you cannot find it out by yourself.